# Creating a DB connection in global.asa with JScript

Tags: javascript, asp-classic, jscript, global.asa

I have a problem. I have this piece of ASP code with JScript like this:

```
var stringa = "Driver=SQL Server;Server=xxx;Database=xxx;Uid=xxx;Pwd=xxx;";
var cn = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection");
var rs = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");
cn.Open(stringa);
var SQL = "SELECT * FROM pippo"
rs.Open(SQL, cn, 1);

// ...

rs.Close();
```

I want to convert this code to two files: global.asa (for the connection) and pippo.asp (for the rest of the code). On the web, I found only code for `global.asa` coded in VBScript, but I want to use JScript.  Can you help me?

Comment: Perhaps showing use exactly what you have in global.asa and what you have in pippo.asp would help.  I would seem to me the only semi-sensible thing you might do is put the connection string in the application object.  For that task does it really matter what language is used?

Answer (score 1):

What I've done in the past is store the connection string as an `Application` variable set in global.asa, and create the `Connection` object on a page-by-page basis.  The syntax for a JScript version of global.asa is going to be very similar to a VBScript version.

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525965%28VS.90%29.aspx):

> When the application starts, the server looks in the Global.asa file
>   and processes the Application_OnStart function. When the application
>   ends, the server processes the Application_OnEnd function.

So a barebones global.asa may look like:

```
<script language="JScript" runat="Server">
    function Application_OnStart() {
        Application.Contents("connString") = "<etc...>";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: OK, thanks for the answer. How can I retrive the code in the pippo.asp  to use "connString"?

Comment: In VBScript it would be Application("connString").  Are you using JScript for a reason?  Dealing with ADO seems cleaner to me in VBScript

Comment: @user1427810, `Application.Contents("connString")`